# Finding index of kth smallest element in an array efficiently (iterative)?

Tags: java, algorithm, median

I would like to find the kth smallest element in an array but actually need its index for my partition method.

I found this code on this blog for finding the kth smallest element:
http://blog.teamleadnet.com/2012/07/quick-select-algorithm-find-kth-element.html

But this only returns the value, not the index.

Do you have any idea how I can find the index of it efficiently?

Comment: How about maintaining numbers in Heap with size k?

Comment: If you can store your values in a `TreeSet`, you'll get quite effective operations with very little work.

Comment: If your array is `[a_1, a_2, ..., a_n]`, you can just run QuickSelect on the augmented array `[(a_1, 1), (a_2, 2), ..., (a_n, n)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to create an additional `indices` array of the same length, fill it by numbers from `0` to `length-1` and when `arr` array is changed, perform the same change with the `indices` array. Finally return the corresponding entry from the `indices` array. You don't even have to understand the original algorithm to do this. Here's the modified method (my changes are marked with `***`):

```
public static int selectKthIndex(int[] arr, int k) {
    if (arr == null || arr.length <= k)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    int from = 0, to = arr.length - 1;

    // ***ADDED: create and fill indices array
    int[] indices = new int[arr.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < indices.length; i++)
        indices[i] = i;

    // if from == to we reached the kth element
    while (from < to) {
        int r = from, w = to;
        int mid = arr[(r + w) / 2];

        // stop if the reader and writer meets
        while (r < w) {

            if (arr[r] >= mid) { // put the large values at the end
                int tmp = arr[w];
                arr[w] = arr[r];
                arr[r] = tmp;
                // *** ADDED: here's the only place where arr is changed
                // change indices array in the same way
                tmp = indices[w];
                indices[w] = indices[r];
                indices[r] = tmp;
                w--;
            } else { // the value is smaller than the pivot, skip
                r++;
            }
        }

        // if we stepped up (r++) we need to step one down
        if (arr[r] > mid)
            r--;

        // the r pointer is on the end of the first k elements
        if (k <= r) {
            to = r;
        } else {
            from = r + 1;
        }
    }

    // *** CHANGED: return indices[k] instead of arr[k]
    return indices[k];
}
```

Note that this method modifies the original `arr` array. If you don't like this, add `arr = arr.clone()` at the beginning of the method.